# Employee Details

Tags: python, spyder

I have a excel sheet containing only "Employee id" in Column A as shown below. These details are saved in a excel sheet named as EmpId.xlsx

```
1677
5597
5623
5618
```

I have one more excel sheet containing "Employee details" of 10000+ Employees. For Eg: The Employee details excel sheet contains contains data of lot of employee here is the example one of employee id shown below. These details are saved in a excel sheet named as UserList.xlsx

```
Empid   Name    Location    JobTitle    Email-id     Department
1677    Umesh     Gadag      ASE      abc@gmail.com    Civil
```

I have a Working Python code, which when i run i get the output. Basically the Empid excel sheet contains only Employee ids and UserList excel sheet contains details of 10000+ Employees. Basically for the EmpIds i get the User list details in the output.Below is the code

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_excel (r'C:\\Users\\Kiran\\Desktop\\PythonWork\\EmpId.xlsx')
df2= pd.read_excel (r'C:\\Users\\Kiran\\Desktop\\PythonWork\\UserList.xlsx')
df1 = df1.reset_index().rename(columns= {"index": "order"})
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = "Empid").sort_values("order").drop("order", axis=1)
df3.to_excel("Output.xlsx",index=False)
import os
file = "Output.xlsx"
os.startfile(file)
```

The code works fine, but there is a Issue. Let us assume i need User details for these 4 EmpIds(1677,5597,5623,5618) When i Run i get output as

```
Empid   Name    Location    JobTitle    Email-id     Department
1677    Umesh     Gadag      ASE      abc@gmail.com    Civil
5597    Rahul     Hubli      ASE      xyz@gmail.com   Electrical
5618    Ramesh    Hubli       SE      pqr@gmail.com     Civil
```

I didnt get output for 5623 thats fine, since may be for Empid 5623 there may not be user list. But in the output i except to get output as:

```
Empid   Name    Location    JobTitle    Email-id     Department
1677    Umesh     Gadag      ASE      abc@gmail.com    Civil
5597    Rahul     Hubli      ASE      xyz@gmail.com   Electrical
5623
5618    Ramesh    Hubli       SE      pqr@gmail.com     Civil
```

So that i can cross check later. How to modify the code so that if for any EmpID  if there is no user list for it i shoudl get as empty as shown above. Can someone guide me to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to include: `how="left"` in the merge

which should show all rows from the left table (df1) and only add what also occured in df2

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = "Empid", how="left").sort_values("order").drop("order", axis=1)
```

Because per [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the default is: `how='inner'` which will throw everything away which is not present in both tables.

Comment: Glad I could help! Could you also accept the answer as accepted answer if it solved the problem? Happy Coding!